# YouTube Embed SSL Errors

Tags: https, embed

Anyone else have problem using a YouTube Embed Code on a https site?
The security warning pops up in Internet Explorer telling your users they are loading unsecured data on a secure site. YouTube doesn't have a SSL installed on their domain.

Anyone know of a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

YouTube *does* have an SSL. Try going to https://www.youtube.com

Just get the embed code and then change all

> http://

to

> https://

Basically, they have an SSL certificate set up. However (and it's worth checking this by clicking on the padlock with the line through it in Chrome) but it's saying that it's got SSL, but there are elements on the page that aren't encrypted.